# 500 server error when saving Symfony entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to couple my application with its database. To do this, I've generated an entity with `doctrine:generate:entity`. It's produced an entity with appropriate annotations for mapping. I've also used `doctrine:schema:update --force` to actually create the schema on the database server, which I can confirm it has done with phpMyAdmin.

In my controller I'm trying to simply insert a row like so:

```
public function testAction() {
    $file = new File();
    $file->setTest('A Foo Bar');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($file);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(array('foo' => 'bar'));
}
```

The entity only has one field called `test` which is string and of length 255. When I request this URL through an AJAX request in my application, it throws back a very uninformative 500 Internal Server Error:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon
>   as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

The PHP error logs also don't have any error information. This controller action does work if I remove the database manipulation stuff. The application is also running in the dev environment.

Is there any way I can get a more descriptive error message to at least tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Do you usually get the Symfony full backtrace error? Did you create an EventListener that triggers onPersist or any other Doctrine event?

Comment: try again after clearing the cache!!!

Comment: Do you run the application in production environment? If so you can try to setup loggin (click [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html#using-several-handlers) to see the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html#using-several-handlers))

Comment: I do usually get the backtrace errors. I'm not sure what you mean by an EventListener that triggers onPersist but I'll look into it. Also cleared the cache and the problem still persists. And I am in the dev environment, as it says in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone here comes across this issue and is lost, the cause in my case was that I had specified a new @ORM\ManyToOne relationship and was persisting instead of merging the entity.

This in the past has returned a valid error, but in this case the php script was not handling it at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default error page that you get in production. You can customize it - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

You can catch and read an error creating `ExceptionListener` - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

Also you can switch to dev environment to show error text and log.

If you just want dev logs but prod environment, you can copy contents of `monolog` section `app/config/config_dev.yml` to `app/config/config_prod.yml`.